# Recorrer consulta con cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Soy nuevo en sql server y estoy aprendiendo sobre cursores. Tengo una consulta donde me traigo unos registros utilizando CASE WHEN para transponer filas a columnas sin necesidad de la función pivot, pero quiero hacer esa misma consulta con un cursor que por lo visto es más dinámico.

Esta es la tabla de donde traigo los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los datos que trae esa consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener esos mismos datos pero con un cursor.

¿Es posible hacer un cursor que tenga la misma funcionalidad que la consulta anterior?.

Comment: un cursor como tal no es posible, un cursor te sirve para recorrer registros de una tabla que tu le proporcionas y ejecutas instrucciones en cada iteración, lo que podrías hacer con el cursor es generar una temporal y en cada iteración hacer el insert.

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto. No como imagen.

Comment: Un cursor es veneno, para Sql Server. Es un recurso, que además de no tener nada dinámico, es procedimental, y TSQL, es un lenguaje de conjuntos, y hay que evitar las bucles. Existen, porque hay situaciones que sin ellos no se resuelven, pero se deberían de evitar a toda costa. Además lo que tienes no es un pivot ni un cursor, es una simple consulta, que contiene una columna repetida varias veces. [Qué es un cursor](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/tutorial-de-cursor-de-sql-server/)

Comment: Estás cayendo en el [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%c3%a9-es-el-problema-xy). Lo mejor es que expliques bien lo que deseas hacer con todas sus reglas.